# Is it possible sorting by column position in linq?

Tags: linq

I am new to Linq. I just want to know how sorting by column position applies in Linq with c# expression. If it is possible please tell me or if not what is the reason behind it?
Like in Sql

```sql
SELECT Title, FirstName, LastName
FROM Employees
ORDER BY 1,3
```

Answer (score 3):

That's not possible in LINQ and bad practice in SQL. Just specify the columns / properties you want to order by.

An equivalent LINQ query is this:

```
employees.Select(x => new { x.Title, x.FirstName, x.LastName })
         .OrderBy(x => x.Title)
         .ThenBy(x => x.LastName);
```

Or in query syntax:

```
from e in employees
order by e.Title, e.LastName
select new { x.Title, x.FirstName, x.LastName };
```

Comment: But how to use your query i mean no from and in clause are there?

Comment: You can use it as is. This is *method chains* syntax. I updated my answer with an equivalent *query* syntax sample.

Comment: @ChintsCoder don't forget to accept answer which helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

Not excatly sure what you mean, but if what you mean is:

```
SELECT Title, FirstName, LastName FROM Employees ORDER BY Title, LastName
```

Then you would so one of the following:

```
var results = from e in context.Employees
              order by e.Title, e.Lastname
              select e;
```

or

```
var results = context.Employees.OrderBy(e => e.Title).ThenBy(e => e.LastName)
```

A good reference for future use:

- [101 LINQ Samples (C#)](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b)
- [101 LINQ Samples (VB.Net)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb688088.aspx)